# Email subscription/unsubscribing extension for joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I need a simple extension which will simply collect email id's from users who want to hear discount offers from me and also allows anybody to unsubscribe from the mailing list.

Which will be the simple and best one for Joomla 1.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following components: [Communicator](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/4600?qh=YTozOntpOjA7czoxMDoibmV3c2xldHRlciI7aToxO3M6MTE6Im5ld3NsZXR0ZXJzIjtpOjI7czoxMjoibmV3c2xldHRlcidzIjt9), [JNews](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/11585?qh=YTozOntpOjA7czoxMDoibmV3c2xldHRlciI7aToxO3M6MTE6Im5ld3NsZXR0ZXJzIjtpOjI7czoxMjoibmV3c2xldHRlcidzIjt9) and [AcaJoom](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/964?qh=YTozOntpOjA7czoxMDoibmV3c2xldHRlciI7aToxO3M6MTE6Im5ld3NsZXR0ZXJzIjtpOjI7czoxMjoibmV3c2xldHRlcidzIjt9)
They are all very easy to use. All of them are provided with component for admin, subscribtion module and plugin to integrate subscribtion form into a article. The most simple is Communicator. I used it more often then others

I hope it is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [AcyMailing](http://www.acyba.com), and would say works perfect. You can create different lists, and export users easily. It supports Joomla 1.5 as well.